# Get the also strings before numeric serarch using regular expression in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string from which I need to use re to get "PASS_MAX_DAYS   180" as an output and then replace it using re.sub to someother value, but when I do a re I am not able to get the sting

```
>>>_file = '#\nPASS_MAX_DAYS   180\nPASS_MIN_DAYS   1\nPASS_WARN_AGE   8\n'

>>> re.findall(r'PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b', _file, re.M)
   ['180']
```

Not sure where I am going wrong, any suggesting please

Comment: >>>` re.findall(r'PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b', _file, re.M)`
['180']

Sorry the whole type changed before

Answer (score 0):

Turn the capturing group to non-capturing group because re.findall function returns only the characters present inside the groups, if the regex used has any capturing groups.

```
r"PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*\b(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b"
```

**Example:**

```
>>> _file = '#\nPASS_MAX_DAYS   180\nPASS_MIN_DAYS   1\nPASS_WARN_AGE   8\n'
>>> re.findall(r'PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*\b(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b', _file, re.M)
['PASS_MAX_DAYS   180']
```

Comment: That just saved my weekend, thank you... I think I have to start studying re much more . Thank you.

Comment: Yes it was working when I used re.search.. the above statement makes sense now .. so much to learn
>>>_new=re.search(r'PASS_MAX_DAYS\s*\b([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-7][0-9]|180)\b', _file, re.M)
>>> _new.group
>>> _new.group()
'PASS_MAX_DAYS   180'